# How do I change the styles dropdown in message templates

Tags: message-templates, templates

How do I change the style dropdown to have my own personal styles in the dropdown in the message templates?

Comment: Please post your CiviCRM version and CMS?  I assume you're asking how to change the list of styles in the WYSIWYG editor, yes?